# vba code to connect mysql database

Tags: mysql, vba

```
Public Sub NewScript(td As TriggerData)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
' TODO: Add your code here
MsgBox ("Hi world")
Dim dbcon As New ADODB.Connection
' Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim dbname As String
Dim servername As String
Dim userid As String
Dim pwd As String
Dim strSql As String
servername = "localhost"
dbname = "world"
userid = "root"
pwd = "admin123"


Set dbcon = New ADODB.Connection

dbcon.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}" _
    & ";SERVER=" & servername _
    & ";DATABASE=" & dbname _
    & ";UID=" & userid _
    & ";PWD=" & pwd _
    & ";Option=3"
    dbcon.Open
    MsgBox "connection open"   
    If dbcon.State = ADODB.adStateOpen Then
        MsgBox "connection success"
        dbcon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Else
        MsgBox "connection fail"
        dbcon.Close
        Set dbcon = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

After database connection line... msgbox "connection open" is not executing

Comment: is the error handler being triggered?

Comment: error is "data source name not found and no default driver specified"